# How compare third one in each array in each line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

If I have two array

```
A = [ "B,C,D"
      "W,F,G"
      "M,S,E"
    ]
D = [E]
```

and want to compare ***D*** OR ***G*** with E (I mean the third one in each line)and If they are equal can show all the line for me. The third one in each line a part of each line and I want just compare the third one If it is equal show that line have equal variable .
I wrote this code but didn't give me the response that I need have :

```
 for(var k=0 ; k<A.length ; k++){
    if(A[k].split(",")[2] === E) {
       finalSuccessServices = A;
       console.log(finalSuccessServices );
     }
```

How can I improve my code to get that line that have my equal variable?

Comment: what is `E`? Why are you setting `finalSuccessServices = A`, when `A` never changes anyways? Did you mean `A[k]`?

Comment: what do you mean with line? please add the wanted result.

Comment: could you please give me the expected output ?

Comment: @ ASDFGerte  exactly A[k] yes

Comment: @Nina Scholz  for example in One line I have "B,C,D"

Comment: @ prasana kannan in my example After comparing I should have : "M,S,E" because I have  "E" in third one in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the array and have a look up with `includes`.

```js
var array = ["B,C,D", "W,F,G", "M,S,E"],
    pattern = ['E'],
    result = array.filter(s => pattern.includes(s.split(',')[2]));

console.log(result);
```

If you need only the first one, take `find`.

```js
var array = ["B,C,D", "W,F,G", "M,S,E"],
    pattern = ['E'],
    result = array.find(s => pattern.includes(s.split(',')[2]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what's the meaning of  s => pattern.includes(s.split(',')[2])

Comment: when You use s=> what is the meaning ?

Comment: it's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a short form of `function () {}` with some special features.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It is makesense for if not equal yes ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If 'E' not equal with third one ?

Comment: sorry, what result do you expect in this case and why is the value to check in an array? can it gave more values?

Comment: Imagine (like opposite this case). you give me example for If 'E' is equal with third one in each line , Now If 'E' NOT equal with third one in each line.

Comment: My result like this :[
  "B,C,D", "W,F,G"
]

Comment: use [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) in front of the includes check, like `!pattern.includes(...)`.

Comment: Thanks again @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` to get the matching string, provided you have a single match:

```js
const A = [ "B,C,D",
      "W,F,G",
      "M,S,E"
    ];
const D = ['E'];

let result = A.find(str => str.split(',')[2] === D[0]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `filter` along with the function `includes` in order to select those lines which have a third letter within the array `D`.

```js
let A = [ "B,C,D", "W,F,G", "M,S,E" ],
    D = ["E"],
    result = A.filter(s => {
      let [,,C] = s.split(",");
      return D.includes(C);
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `split` and destructure to get third element
2. Compare third value and first (from array D)
3. Console log and push to finalSuccessServices array.

```js
const A = ["B,C,D", "W,F,G", "M,S,E"];
const D = ["E"];

const [first] = D;
const finalSuccessServices = [];
A.forEach(line => {
  const [,, third] = line.split(",");
  if (third === first) {
    console.log(line);
    finalSuccessServices.push(line);
  }
});

console.log("finalSuccessServices", finalSuccessServices);
```